# iOS App crashed com.apple.root.background-qos

Tags: ios, swift, observers, crash

An app crash was found in the application. I suspect that this could happen because of the code for firebase observers. Since in a user case, a user can go from one event to a user profile (which participates in this event) then from the user profile can go back to this event I needed a handle for ref to delete a specific observer. Because of this, I made the following code.

Snippet of code

```
fileprivate func firObserve(_ isObserve: Bool) {
    guard card != nil else { return }
    firCardObserverDBManager.observeParticipationCard(observer: self, card: card, isObserve: isObserve, success: { [weak self] (updatedCard) in
            debugPrint("updated card")
            self?.checkUpdatedCard(updatedCard)
        }, removed: { [weak self] in
            self?.isParticipationCardDateRemoved = true
            self?.presentCardRemovedAlert()
    }) { (error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

from FIRCardObserverDBManager

```
    fileprivate var observeParticipationCardObservers = NSMapTable<AnyObject, AnyObject>(keyOptions: .weakMemory, valueOptions: .strongMemory)


func observeParticipationCard(observer: Any, card: CardModel, isObserve: Bool, success: ((_ updatedCard: CardModel) -> Void)?, removed: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child(MainGateways.cards.rawValue).child(card.id)

    if !isObserve {
        guard let handle = self.observeParticipationCardObservers.object(forKey: observer as AnyObject) as? UInt else { return }
        ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
        observeParticipationCardObservers.removeObject(forKey: observer as AnyObject)
        return
    }

    if let observableVC = observer as? UIViewController {
        observableVC.firReferences.append(ref)
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let handle = ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                // not exist
                removed?()
            }
            guard let json = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            guard let updatedCard = Mapper<CardModel>().map(JSON: json) else { return }
            success?(updatedCard)
        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            fail?(error)
        })
        self.observeParticipationCardObservers.setObject(handle as AnyObject, forKey: observer as AnyObject)
        debugPrint("observeParticipationCardObservers", self.observeParticipationCardObservers)
    }
}
```

an UIViewController's extension for it

```
extension UIViewController {

    private struct FirebaseQueues {
        static var firQueues = [DatabaseQuery]()
    }

    var firQueues: [DatabaseQuery] {
        get {
            guard let firQueues = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &FirebaseQueues.firQueues) as? [DatabaseQuery] else { return [] }
            return firQueues
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &FirebaseQueues.firQueues, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    private struct FirebaseReferences {
        static var firReferences = [DatabaseReference]()
    }

    var firReferences: [DatabaseReference] {
        get {
            guard let firReferenses = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &FirebaseReferences.firReferences) as? [DatabaseReference] else { return [] }
            return firReferenses
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &FirebaseReferences.firReferences, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    func removeFIRQueuesReferensesObservers() {
        for firQueqry in firQueues {
            firQueqry.removeAllObservers()
        }
        firQueues.removeAll()
        for firRef in firReferences {
            firRef.removeAllObservers()
        }
        firReferences.removeAll()
    }

}
```

Crash stack

```
   Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
    0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1022ba574 swift_unknownRelease (__hidden#21375_:381)
    1  myapp                       0x1002e3fd0 specialized specialized _ArrayBufferProtocol._arrayOutOfPlaceUpdate<A where ...> (inout _ContiguousArrayBuffer<A.Element>, Int, Int, A1) -> () (EventsUpcomingVC.swift)
    2  myapp                       0x1002e0eb8 specialized Array._copyToNewBuffer(oldCount : Int) -> () (EventsUpcomingVC.swift)
    3  myapp                       0x100319a84 specialized ChatGeneralManager.(observeConversationModel(Bool, conversationID : String, updated : () -> ()?, fail : (Error) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ChatGeneralManager.swift)
    4  myapp                       0x100311f70 ChatGeneralManager.(observeConversationModel(Bool, conversationID : String, updated : () -> ()?, fail : (Error) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ChatGeneralManager.swift)
    5  myapp                       0x10032515c partial apply for ChatGeneralManager.(observeConversationModel(Bool, conversationID : String, updated : () -> ()?, fail : (Error) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ChatGeneralManager.swift)
    6  libdispatch.dylib              0x185b9e9e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    7  libdispatch.dylib              0x185b9e9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    8  libdispatch.dylib              0x185baebac _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 888
    9  libdispatch.dylib              0x185bae7d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
    10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185da7100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
    11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185da6cac start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let handle = ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                // not exist
                removed?()
            }

This seems to be the issue, even calling this statement where you have called could cause crash. ~Try to comment this line or add exception break point to confirm is this code causing crash ?

Comment: @cole See, the problem is that I can not reproduce this app crash, so I can not know for sure if this section of code or another piece of code is bug or not. Tell me please, why do you think that this is the problem here?

Comment: I am helping to debug the issue to solve the problem. The first step to understand what causing crash. It seems from your crash log 
 com.apple.root.background-qos
This is thread request which might be over committed due to which it exist as it cannot take any more request.
Hope it helps

Comment: Just try to take that piece of code out or comment out. Just to see it still cause crash or same crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that the data app crashes happen because of the incorrect functions in the runtime. After changing the function, I no longer have app crashes.

```
private var queuesKey = 0
private var referencesKey = 1

extension UIViewController {

    var firQueues: [DatabaseQuery]? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &queuesKey) as? [DatabaseQuery]
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &queuesKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    var firReferences: [DatabaseReference]? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &referencesKey) as? [DatabaseReference]
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &referencesKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }


    func removeFIRQueuesReferensesObservers() {
        if var _firQueues = firQueues {
            for firQueqry in _firQueues {
                firQueqry.removeAllObservers()
            }
//            debugPrint("removeFIRQueuesReferensesObservers _firQueues start", _firQueues.count, "firQueues", firQueues?.count ?? "nil")
            _firQueues.removeAll()
            firQueues?.removeAll()
//            debugPrint("removeFIRQueuesReferensesObservers _firQueues end", _firQueues.count, "firQueues", firQueues?.count ?? "nil")
        }

        if var _firReferences = firReferences {
            for firRef in _firReferences {
                firRef.removeAllObservers()
            }
//            debugPrint("removeFIRQueuesReferensesObservers _firReferences start", "_firReferences", _firReferences.count, "firReferences", firReferences?.count ?? "nil")
            _firReferences.removeAll()
            firReferences?.removeAll()
//            debugPrint("removeFIRQueuesReferensesObservers _firReferences end", "_firReferences", _firReferences.count, "firReferences", firReferences?.count ?? "nil")
        }
    }

}
```